# AWS Amplify www and non www domain different load speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have an angular app hosted with amplify. I’ve added a custom domain. I can access my site with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and with example.com. The issue is that when I go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) app loads super fast. But when I go to example.com it takes 10x times more time.

As both urls lead to my site I assume that I set up dns correctly (on namecheap).

Could you please help me?

I don't know what to try as this is a mistery for me. Both link lead to different IPs - maybe this is the issue. But I don't know how solve it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by migrating DNS to AWS Route53 following this instruction: https://aws.plainenglish.io/how-to-connect-your-domain-from-namecheap-to-amazon-route-53-840bc745ce67. Also I have to add A and CNAME records to the created Hosted Zone. Now both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) are loaded fast.
So the issue was with DNS but what exactly I don't know. Maybe I'll try to figure that out and update the answer.